# Sequentially call asynchronous methods in a loop

Tags: c#, multithreading, events

I'm working with some code, that has an approach I've never dealt with before, and am hoping someone might be able to provide a spark of knowledge:

Effectively the class is setup like this:

```
void Loop()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        //need to block calls to this until UpdateComplete is hit
        Update(i);
    }
}

void Update(int i)
{
    //asynchronous - returns immediately
}

void UpdateComplete()//called from another thread
{
    //unblock further calls to Update();
}
```

The big caveat is that it's not possible to call `Update()` before `UpdateComplete()` has 'returned' or been calledback.

Ignoring any UI side effects, is there a neat solution to this problem?

I've currently got two strategies - one hacky and one I feel is over-complicated:

1 - Hacky: Set a global class boolean `IsBlocked`, that `Update()` sets to `true` and `UpdateComplete()` sets to false, and inside my for loop (in `Loop()`), just put in a `while (IsBlocked){}`.

2 - Over-complicated: Get rid of the loop altogether. Call `Update(0);` from inside `Loop()` instead, and have `UpdateComplete()` call `Update(1);`, `Update(2);` and so on.

I guess I'm hoping for something like a `Thread.Pause` that can then be remotely 'resumed' by another thread (the separate one that calls `UpdateComplete()`
Any ideas appreciated!

Comment: I would use `async/await`

Comment: Put the code where it belongs.  Add another argument to Update(), a bool named "executeAsychronously".

Comment: Both ways you describe do not offer any advantage of threading. They effectively run on a single thread at all times, they just jump from one thread to another. So it only complicates matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Async/await can also be used here

```
TaskCompletionSource<object> tcs = null;

async void Loop()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
        Update(i);
        await tcs.Task;
    }
}

void Update(int i)
{
    //asynchronous - returns immediately
}

void UpdateComplete()//called from another thread
{
    tcs.TrySetResult(null);
    //unblock further calls to Update();
}
```

Comment: This is cool - I take it `tcs.TrySetResult(null);` will work when called from a different thread?

Comment: @maxp Yes, BTW: if you have some data in `UpdateComplete` to return to `Loop` method you can pass it by `TrySetResult`. Then your await code would be `var some data =  await tcs.Task`

Answer (score 0):

Post the updates into the thread pool using QueueUserWorkItem

Have a counter of the number of posted items.

Have main thread wait on AutoResetEvent

When Each update finishes decrement the count under lock.

When the count hits 0 Set the AutoResetEvent to awake the main thread

I didn't post any code cos I assumed you can google how to do each bit, if not comment and I can add code

Comment: Interesting, I'll have a look into that (btw not my downvote)

Comment: @maxp if this approach sounds reasonable to you you should update your question - currently it sounds like all items *must* be handled sequentially (while this post suggest parallel execution). - that mismatch could be reason of (not mine) downvote, and also prevents upvoting this post.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Yes you're correct, they must be sequential.

Comment: @maxp - I've updated title of the post based on this comment - please check and rollback/update if necessary.